# How create dynamic list with class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Good afternoon,
I want to create dynamic list with class in C++ like C# list, its possible ?
Thank you in advance for your help,

The solution: use vector
Include vector library

```
#include <vector>
```

create variable

```
std::vector<MyClass>  vect;
```

Reserve memory, can improve speed with huge vector (it's optional)

```
vect.reserve(10);

for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
       //Vector create and add class instance into vector
       vect.emplace_back(/*Arguments for constructor*/);

       //Acces to public methods and variables in class
       std::cout << vect[i]./*methods or variables name*/;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: -1073741819 is 0xC0000005 in base 16, the windows exception code for access violation

Comment: You create a vector of `i` elements in each loop iteration. This means maximum index you can access is `i-1` (except for when `i` is 0)

Comment: You probably don't want to declare `std::vector<MyClass>  arr` inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are recreating the arr 11 time in your loop i think you meant to do this :

```
//the error is generated because you are trying to access an element out of bounds because your declaration is wrong 
std::vector<MyClass>  arr;
for(unsigned long long i = 0 ; i<=10;i++){
       arr.emplace_back( 10,20+i);
        std::cout << arr[i].ggg;
    }
```